# Como elimino el mensaje de "Copied" que tiene mi pagina de wordpress arriba del todo en el lado izquierdo?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

Mi pagina de Wordpress tiene un mensaje que dice "Copied!" en la esquina superior del lado izquierdo y no tengo ni idea de como removerlo de ahi.
Pensaba que solo yo como administrador lo podia ver. Ya tiene un tiempo ahi, recien me doy cuenta de que todos lo ven porque un compañero me lo comento.

[image: Imagen]

Así es como luce cuando lo veo con la herramienta de desarrollador de Google (lo subraye en amarillo para que resalte)

[image: Imagen2]

Podrían por favor decirme como removerlo?

Comment: El mensaje puede estar dado por un plugin, si usas chrome ve a **Más Herramientas -> Herramientas de desarrollador** y seleccionas el mensaje. De ahí edita tu pregunta y muestra el codigo que se esta generando.

Comment: Esta bien, dejame probar

Comment: Puedes poner el código del header.php de tu tema ?